# How to check if a particular cell in pandas DataFrame isnull?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df` in pandas.

```
0       A     B     C
1       2   NaN     8
```

How can I check if `df.iloc[1]['B']` is NaN?

I tried using `df.isnan()` and I get a table like this:

```
0       A     B      C
1   false  true  false
```

but I am not sure how to index the table and if this is an efficient way of performing the job at all?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [`pd.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), for select use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (df)
   0  A   B  C
0  1  2 NaN  8

print (df.loc[0, 'B'])
nan

a = pd.isnull(df.loc[0, 'B'])
print (a)
True

print (df['B'].iloc[0])
nan

a = pd.isnull(df['B'].iloc[0])
print (a)
True
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error: TypeError: isnull() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: I had written `df.isnull(df['B'].iloc[0])` instead of `pd.isnull(df['B'].iloc[0])`. Thank you this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

jezrael response is spot on. If you are only concern with NaN value, I was exploring to see if there's a faster option, since in my experience, summing flat arrays is (strangely) faster than counting. This code seems faster:

```
df.isnull().values.any()
```

For example:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,1000))

In [3]: df[df > 0.9] = pd.np.nan

In [4]: %timeit df.isnull().any().any()
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit df.isnull().values.sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.isnull().sum().sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 18 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.isnull().values.any()
1000 loops, best of 3: 948 µs per loop
```

Comment: This does not check a particular cell.

Comment: how to check if a particular cell is nan e,g df['colname'].values[0] is empty how to check this
pd.isnull - return bool or array depending on value is empty or not empty but its throwing error when used in if condition

Comment: for select use loc or iloc:

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the indexes of NaN in a specific column you can use

```
list(df['B'].index[df['B'].apply(np.isnan)])
```

In case you what to get the indexes of all possible NaN values in the dataframe you may do the following

```
row_col_indexes = list(map(list, np.where(np.isnan(np.array(df)))))
indexes = []
for i in zip(row_col_indexes[0], row_col_indexes[1]):
    indexes.append(list(i))
```

And if you are looking for a one liner you can use:

```
list(zip(*[x for x in list(map(list, np.where(np.isnan(np.array(df)))))]))
```